# Is cat7 cable appropriate for an office network?

Tags: wiring, ethernet

I am looking to update my network, and would like to run 2 lengths of Cat 7 wire from my first floor office to where my patch panel is. (Planning to put a NAS down there, and run 10Gb to/from.)

The length I need is less than 50 ft (X2) and in my search for Cat 7 wire, I am not finding bulk cable less than 500 feet, which seems a waste. I find 50 foot lengths of cable with the connectors at each end.

Before I do something I'll regret, I am asking if there's any reason not to use this wire.

Comment: Any reason not to use CAT7, or reason not to use pre-made cables, or...? If you're considering additional at some point in the future, having the spool sitting around could be considered motivation to do so.

Comment: @FreeMan - a 500 foot spool of CAT7 looks to be between $150-$200 from a quick search. If he only needs 100 ft of it, that's a fair bit of money to leave sitting around.

Comment: The bulk I see is $200 for 500 ft, vs $30 total for the two 50 ft lengths. Will continue to search a local place to buy by the foot.

Comment: Is SFP+ (or SFP) available at both ends? Two transceivers and a bit of pre-terminated fibre could be a cost-effective option, especially considering that shafts between floors tend to have power in them, and fibre is not affected by the proximity of that sort of power.

Comment: I was planning RJ45 receptacles at the ends. I will ponder your suggestion.

Comment: Cat6 will do 10GBase-T up to 60m. If your runs are shorter than this, there is no point in Cat7, only extra cost.

Comment: @SiHa: And harder installation. Cat6 is more flexible.

Comment: This is arguably an XY problem https://xyproblem.info/ as OP is asking about a solution rather than a requirement. As I understand it, the requirement is 10gb/s transfer to the NAS, so this is the aspect that should be addressed.

Comment: Put a duct in the wall, then it doesnt matter what you run - if you don't like it you tie something that you do like to the end of the thing you don't like and pull..

Comment: Conduit. Run conduit. Then worry about what goes in the conduit, without needing to worry about what you might want in the future, because it will be easy in the future to change what's inside the conduit.

Comment: Not everyone *can* run conduit. In England, most of our houses are not built with as much drywall as I understand houses in the USA have, so we have to chase channels I to the brick walls.

Comment: @JamesGeddes - "In England, most of our houses are not built with as much drywall as I understand houses in the USA have" - and we tend to call it 'plasterboard', don't we?

Comment: I was translating into American English :D

Comment: It's not the wall material that matters, it's the empty space inside.  In the US it's called a "void" but in the UK it's filled with Marmite and Jam.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you run cat7 into a cat5e patch panel, you will get cat5e performance, not the 10gb/s you are looking for. To get cat7 performance from your cat7 cable, you would need a cat7 patch panel, cat7 modules and cat7 RJ45 jacks. These are all harder to install than their cat5e equivalents.

Cat6a can maintain 10 Gbps over up to 100 meters but without the huge cost hike of cat7. As 50'≈15m, you are well within the distance limitation, but would be at the upper limit of the speed that copper - any copper - is capable of. Equally, you need to pair it with cat6a patch panels, modules and RJ45's to avoid bottlenecks.

As I understand it, your core requirement is fast transfer to your NAS, rather than being desperate to install cat7 for the fun of cable installation. As you need 10gb/s today, I would expect this to grow over time, and since 10gb/s is the upper limit of what copper is capable of you could quickly run out of capacity if you use copper. The speed of copper cable is limited by the fact that the cable is made of copper, whereas the speed of fibre optic cable is limited only by the kit that you connect to it - and you can upgrade that in the future much easier than you can install a new cable. Yes, Cat8 might technically be capable of 40Gbps, but that's it. When you buy a shiny new 100Gb/s network switch in the [potentially near future](https://www.fs.com/uk/products/115385.html), your copper will be useless but your fibre will keep on trucking. I should also note that ***400gbps*** networks exist in data centres *today* ([Cisco](https://www.cisco.com/c/en_uk/solutions/data-center/high-capacity-400g-data-center-networking/index.html), [Juniper](https://www.juniper.net/us/en/solutions/400g.html#)), so we could see that in the consumer space in the next decade.

For high performance applications, you will not want to be limited to 10gb/s forever. For example, the [Insta360 Titan](https://www.insta360.com/product/insta360-titan/) can already do spherical video, often colloquially called "VR", in ***11k***. Insta360 have told me via email that one minute of footage can require up to 10.8 gigabytes of storage. On an ideal 1.25 gigabyte per second connection (1 gigabit = 0.125 gigabytes) it would take almost five minutes to transfer a 30 minute video file today. What about when the next thing is released that has even bigger files? With copper, you are already working on the upper limits and its stuck in your walls, so you will just have to suck up the time increase. With fibre, however, you would just upgrade your NIC & switches. The aforementioned 400 gigabit per second setup would transfer the same video file in about *6 seconds*.

**Positives**

- Fibre optic cable is not vastly more expensive than Cat6a.
- Speeds can be bonkers fast.
- Distances can be bonkers long (kilometres).
- Electromagnetic interference is not a concern.

**Negatives**

- No Power over Ethernet.
- Installation can be a pain - optical fibre is glass so ensure that you get a pullable product.
- Photonic kit is still more expensive.
- Cable termination is a pain.
- Not as widely adopted as copper in the consumer space - only your most nerdy friends will have a photonic/SFP+ NIC.

I would suggest running 4 Cat6a cables to each room in your house, alongside 2 fibre optic cables. This still allows you to use PoE, but also gives you the god-like transfer speeds where needed. For us in the more rainy side of the pond, four RJ45 euro modules also conveniently fills a double gang faceplate, though I appreciate that these might look a little unusual for all yall on the other side of said pond.

Regarding purchasing more cable than you need, never run one of anything.

- It will inevitably break leaving you with another job. While you have got the floorboards up, you might as well throw another cable or three in there; cable is cheap, ripping the carpet, floorboards, walls etc up *again* is expensive.
- In two years you will wish you had "just put one more port right there". This is why every room in my house has at least 4 Ethernet ports.

If you are putting one cable in, it takes about the same amount of effort to put 4 cables in, so you might as well put in 4. Additionally, it is always helpful to have spare cable in stock just in case.

## TL;DR

I would strongly suggest dumping copper entirely for this application and going with optical fibre. It is the most cost effective and future proof option.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't run a 3/4" ENT or equivalent at that rate, then pull say 1 Cat6a and 1 fiber pair thru oit?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel If, by ENT, you mean Electrical Nonmetallic Tubing Conduit, then yes, this can help you to install fibre, but as fibre is so delicate I would not put anything else in the conduit. Also, conduit is not really necessary for copper.

Comment: Then again, I am in England so check your local building regulations.

Comment: Having recently crawled through the attic of our church replacing all our crappy, old, dying, poorly run CAT5 cable with _two_ runs each of CAT6 (well laid, avoiding all the electrical cabling up there instead of being zip tied to it), I can wholly endorse the "run 2 of everything because it's easier to do it now while you're there instead of doing it all again later" philosophy!

Comment: @FreeMan Wholeheartedly agreed, though I'd go one step further with the belt and braces approach of running 4 while you are at it. If you run one cable and one cable dies, you have lost 100% of your connectivity. If you run two cables and one dies, you have lost 50% of your connectivity. If you run 4 cables and one cable dies, you have only lost 25% of your connectivity. Future proofing and redundancy FTW.

Comment: With the one drawback that more cable = more expense and church budgets are tight, while church volunteer labor is, well, volunteered... ;)

Comment: A good point well made! I appreciate we are now after the fact, however if you were to get 4 boxes of cable, you could pull all 4 cables through at once. This would save time and a friendly local IT company might even let you buy cable out of their boxes rather than having to purchase entire boxes yourself. Just thoughts for next time I guess :D

Comment: "since 10gb/s is the upper limit of what copper is capable of" is not a true statement, although it's much easier to get faster speeds from fiber. Copper has line losses associated with capacitance and inductance along the line. Fiber has losses associated with light loss along the line. The light loss is easier to deal with which makes it the better choice for faster speeds. Both cause problems the longer the distance is.

Comment: I appreciate this detailed answer. My office will have a 10Gb switch, and the cables talked about here will run off that, to NAS in basement. The rest of the house will still be limited to 1Gb, as the house was built with Cat 5e long ago.

Comment: If you can avoid client side switches, do. If you rely on one cable and put a switch on it, when the switch dies or the cable dies, all those devices lose connection. More cables is better.

Comment: @JamesGeddes you’ve still got a switch somewhere. If you do direct cables, now when your one switch fails, everything fails? Plus, although more small switches means a higher chance of failure, they’re also cheaper, so it’s easy to keep a spare on hand?

Comment: `Installation is a pain - glass breaks easily.` Nonsense - builder grade SMF has been available for years.  Look up Corning ClearCurve - it's fishable/pullable, meant for residential builders and can be installed with staple guns and hard 90-deg bends, and it's completely affordable.

Comment: Just to be clear, what do you mean by SMF?

Comment: @J... I am guessing you mean "Single Mode Fibre" - I just like to be clear as there are so many TLAs, Three Letter Acronyms, around :D

Comment: @J... I have updated the answer to reflect your suggestion.

Comment: @Tim Can your network [survive a pug](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wwwAXlE4OtU)? I am not against switches overall, I am just suggesting that redundancy can help to avoid several headaches. If you put in more cables and one breaks, then plan B is throw a switch at the client side. If plan A is fewer cables and a switch and then one cable breaks, then it's hammer time.

Comment: @Tim On the other hand, one can over engineer something. I have been in IT for ~10 years and have seen just one switch die. (I am not sure if that number is representative.) In industry, on a scale of 0 to "someone is going home with a P45/pink slip today," downtime is right up there, as 5 minutes downtime can cost significantly more than *many* redundant devices, so we put redundancy everywhere to mitigate that risk. At home, however, it might just be annoying; it just depends how much one relies on the connection and your personal risk management strategy. Cost–benefit analysis FTW.

Comment: @JamesGeddes Yes, single-mode.

Comment: "*the Insta360 Titan can already do VR in 11k (~ 602.17GB per minute)), 10gb/s will start to feel pretty slow pretty quickly.*" Considering that 602.17GB per minute equates to ~10gb/s, how does that mean that '10gb/s will feel slow pretty quickly'? There aren't even 11K displays yet; most people have never even seen an 8K display either. Maybe some time in the 2030s, 11K will start to be a thing at stores.

Comment: @TylerH My point is that we are already at the max of what most copper can handle so for high performance requirements, one might as well go for fibre.

Comment: @TylerH Two additional points related to your comment on the example: a) One would normally want to transfer files at faster than realtime playback speed, especially when scrubbing around a video editing timeline. b) Spherical video, often colloquially referred to as VR, requires significantly higher resolution than "normal" video as the image is stretched out so that a viewer can clearly see one part at once. For example, if you have a 4K spherical video, the Head Mounted Display will show a ~720P section of it.

Comment: @JamesGeddes If you are editing a big video/VR/coding/etc. project with the source contents on a NAS or anywhere else, you're doing it wrong. It's *extremely* inefficient compared to having files locally (for all sorts of reasons). Push to the NAS when you are ready to save/publish/etc.

Comment: @TylerH Surely that's even more reason to have faster than real time transfer speeds then? When I go to edit my 2 hour Titan movie, I don't want to have to wait 2 hours to grab it from the NAS.

Comment: @JamesGeddes Why delete local files each time if you have such a large amount of source data? That's another massive waste of time vs using the NAS as a backup/intermediary environment. Anyway, this is all unnecessarily academic; OP is an author and blogger so they are probably not editing future-gen VR/imaginary-K resolution video footage on a regular basis. In reality, 1gb/s would likely suit them just fine for the next 5-10 years for streaming movies to the home entertainment system.

Comment: @TylerH We might be getting caught in the weeds of my example. Since the original spec asked for 10gb/s, I think my point still stands; 10gb/s is the upper limit of what copper is capable of, whereas optical fibre theoretically has no limit. Installing optical fibre would, therefore, be the most cost effective and future proof option.

Comment: @TylerH Thought you might like to know that I have updated my answer as I got the calculations in my video example slightly incorrect. Fibre is still the most future proof solution though ;)

Comment: @JamesGeddes To be clear, I agree with you on the fiber suggestion as the best/most future-proof material, and had already upvoted your answer before my initial comment. My issue was only with the suggestion that someone editing imaginary-K-density footage in real time is not a particularly relevant (or arguably even real-world) example, so much so that I think it detracts from the usefulness of the answer.

Comment: @TylerH Thanks, much appreciated. Agreed, on reflection that was not the best example :)

Answer (score 14):

**Use fiber instead**

Cat7 is still esoteric (you need not just cabling, but Cat7 Ethernet equipment) and you'll be hard pressed to get shorter runs. Fiber is readily available and is not only easily added into existing networks, but you can easily find 10GB SFP adapters to work with most networking equipment.

Comment: In general, I suggest installing the best cabling within reason. I can't really describe what within reason means because that's up to the person paying and installing. If Cat7 is run, but Cat5 connectors are put on the speeds may be lower, but the connectors are much easier to upgrade later than the cable that's already been run. In a commercial environment this may not be a big deal, but in residential it may not be practical.

Comment: Cat7 is also not even (ever going to be) compliant IIRC; you will need Cat8 to fit the full MHz spectrum required by the spec.

Answer (score 6):

Pre-terminated cables are usually stranded wire, the bulk wire is usually solid.

If you intend to cut off the RJ-45 ends and punch down the cables you may have   have difficulty with the stranded wires. If you intend to use the existing termination I think either would be fine.

Stranded wires are more flexible but as I understand it are not as good as solid for signal integrity. But probably not enough to matter for this application.

Comment: Just to clarify. Pre-made cables *will* be stranded. Punch-down connectors *must* use solid-core, so cutting the ends off and re-terminating to keystone jacks isn't an option. You can get RJ45 'ends' for either, but you need to be careful to ensure you get the right type.

Comment: This. A suitability answer that I did not know. And one that kept me from a huge potential mistake. Much thanks.

Comment: Upvoting because I was not aware that pre-terminated cables are stranded.

Comment: This is not *always* true; e.g. I bought a 200 ft solid Cat6a cable (with the intent to chop it up for two long runs).  It came with ends on it, but it was definitely sold as shielded solid, not stranded.  Bug again, that was for a 200 ft cable, not a bulk reel but not a shorter length that could fall into "patch cable" length.  Certainly the default assumption is that cables with ends will be stranded, but if it specifically says solid it's not a contradiction for it to come with ends like @SiHa is saying.

Answer (score 3):

Pre-made cables are harder to pull through walls and tight spaces than connector-less cables. If that's not a problem, then I can't see any reason not to use pre-made cables. If you buy good ones, you know the termination is good as well as the wire.

Since you seem comfortable with the idea of terminating cables yourself, you could also look at buying a 125 ft pre-made cable and cutting the ends off. It's more expensive than just getting the cable, but way cheaper than buying a 500 ft spool that you only want to use 1/5 of.

Comment: This doesn't address the actual question, which is about suitability. You've mostly answered a shopping question, which would be off topic.

Comment: I tried to focus my question on suitability, without hiding my motive. To Michael - the basement ceiling is open and I can see the wire feeding a nearby outlet, so the new hole will be okay to fish through.

Comment: @isherwood - fair. I'm afraid my brain sort of glossed over that point, because 'cat 7' defines cable specs. If it's sold as cat 7 and no one is lying, then, well, it's suitable, because the only thing we know is the OP wants cat 7 from point a to point b.